# Low-hanging fruit for new editors

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Editing tips and tricks](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/830/editing-tips-and-tricks)

There are about [80 questions](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%22sudo+gedit%22) containing `sudo gedit`. As you know, using `sudo` with graphical applications / tools is discouraged, so I think we should replace it with `gksudo` in those questions/answers.

Jorge Castro had the idea to spare those "easy edits" for new low-rep editors as an easy starting point for contributors.

We also could collect bad practices and list corresponding search links, so people can just clean up the site as we go along.

Answer (score 2):

**What to edit:**

- Edit question titles that start with a lower case letter, if appropriate
- Edit out improper punctuation such as "?!!!", "!!", ".."

  - Improve punctuation, such as "logs : bla" → "logs: bla"
- Fix grammar and spelling

  - Especially users who don't speak very good English, I find, appreciate the help
- Edit out obvious words, as in "WoW doesn't run in Ubuntu" → "WoW doesn't run"
- Fix links and images

  - Links should seldom be just URLs:

    - `see this: http://example.com` → `[see this](http://example.com/)`
  - Images should be hosted on imgur. Copy the image URL, click the Image button on the editor and upload it again "from the web". This way, we'll have far fewer dead links.

**How to find posts:**

- Your first stop should be the [Review Page](https://askubuntu.com/review)
- You can use [Advanced Super Ninja Search Options](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=) to find posts to edit

  - For example: [`title:Ubuntu`](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=title%3AUbuntu)

---

Almost every post can be improved in some way. Small and trivial edits are discouraged, so, if you decide to edit a post, make it rock!

Answer (score 0):

If there are 80 questions with tags that need to be renamed or merged, a diamond moderator should do it using the admin tools for merging and renaming tags.

Otherwise, you will be cluttering up the homepage with 80 bumped questions for no very good reason.

Comment: It's actually content, not tags. The 80 questions/answers are an extreme example I guess. A list like suggested by @JorgeCastro could be an easy way for new users to contribute by suggesting edits (e.g., "Windoze" -> "Windows", "QT" -> "Qt", etc.). The problem with bumping can be solved by adding a way to mark an edit as small/cosmetic, which then won't bump the question, but that's a different story (and has probably already been suggested/discussed).

Comment: @htorque we don't support this concept of "minor" edits, it's just a way of sweeping things under the rug. The *correct* way to do mass changes is by contacting a moderator.

Comment: No doubt, but as I said, it's an extreme example. Such a list could point to like 5-15 new questions/answers containing bad practices (which - other than in the above example - already have been taken care of so far).