# How to contact a moderator?

Tags: support, moderators

Seeing [this question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1064/low-hanging-fruit-for-new-editors-closed) I wanted to contact a moderator for changing all `sudo gedit` to `gksu gedit`.

how do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We usually hang out in the [**chat**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), you can contact us there. If something is wrong with a particular question, answer, or comment, you can *flag it for moderator attention*.

Changing every occurrence of `sudo gedit` is not something we can do. We rely on editors to make those changes, one by one. If you don't have the necessary 2000 reputation, you can submit an edit for review, one of the 2000+ users will approve it for you.

Please note:

- When it comes to editing, you don't have to rely on talking to a moderator.

  Any user with more than 2000 reputation has the privilege to edit questions and answers without review. The community trusts them to make the right changes.

In any case, you're very welcome to talk to all of us about it first. If your question is more complex, open a new question on Meta. Join us in the [AskUbuntu General room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room).