# Correcting people's questions.

Tags: support

Is there anything wrong with me going through Ask Ubuntu and correcting spelling and grammar in questions? I want to help but I don't want to be the annoying guy that fills up the edit queue.

Comment: Trust me moderators love when the community self-regulates. When the community makes the edits, closes the poor questions, and helps users out :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's absolutely encouraged and is a great contribution. It feels like we never have enough things in the editing queue. :)

- [Editing tips and tricks](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/830/editing-tips-and-tricks)