# Troublesome tags that need cleaning up

Tags: discussion, tags

We've got a ton of incoming questions and I've realized some tags really do need some love, so I'm going to make a list of the worst ones:

Answer (score 5):

- [broadcom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/broadcom) - specifically questions having to do with BCM4311 need de duping.
- [boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/boot) - IMO our worst tag, these are hard because they're "my computer won't boot"
- [software-center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-center) - A bunch of these seem like bug reports.
- [upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/upgrade) - Probably a bunch of too localized bug reports.
- [nvidia-optimus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/nvidia-optimus) - these are really troublesome in linux and we need a way to point everyone to one canonical question that makes sense for a bunch of people.

Comment: Basically go through a whole bunch of questions and reading them to see if the tag is appropriate? Yes?

Comment: @Luis No, the tags are appropriate, it's just they might contain a bunch of dupes and need a once over, for example today we had like 5 bcm4311 questions that could have been merged, things like that.

Comment: Got it Bot. Will do, after all, robot will take over the world. Better start respecting them already.