# How can we improve the 'greatest hits' of our site?

Tags: discussion

I was reading the Stack Overflow blog earlier today regarding the [greatest hits](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/stack-exchanges-greatest-hits/) of the Stack Exchange sites.

I realize that these posts are what make our site popular across the Internetz and hence, I think we should work to make them even better.

I feel that things like adding screenshots where necessary, editing the titles and body for a clearer answer and retagging appropriately such that the questions even more discoverable can be done to improve the quality of the site.

Thoughts?

(*On a side note, I have edited a [couple](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67946/force-alt-tab-switcher-to-display-applications-from-active-workspace/67951#67951) [of my](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67924/where-are-my-recent-documents-in-unity/67926#67926) [answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66653/cannot-use-meta-d-to-show-desktop/66667#66667) that were featured in the greatest hits to make it slightly better than before. I would love some feedback on that.*)

Comment: To which I reply: EDIT EDIT UPVOTE EDIT BOUNTY EDIT EDIT EDIT. ;)

Comment: This is also mentioned as improving posts with rewarded with badges that indicates lots of hits in http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/830/editing-tips-and-tricks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We should do what the CHAOS team did. Improving, improving and improving some more by editing, editing and yet again editing.

The editing involves, fixing up stylistic errors, fixing the general structure, grammar and adding screenshots where appropriate.

Comment: One of the things we noticed is that making titles look shiny (and, by extension, question bodies and stuff) is only part of the battle -- the title should be *searchable* and accurately reflect the body. It wasn't all capitalization and question marks; we also really analyzed the questions to make sure the bodies and the titles matched up correctly. Along the way, we would answer unanswered questions, as well.

Comment: Sounds like a good point. Thanks for the input. I appreciate every bit of information.