# Let's tag our questions properly

Tags: discussion, tags

<sub>I'm just posting this as a proxy for jokerdino. He can't post because of internet problems, but we both agree this needs to get out *now*.</sub>

<sub>Also, special thanks to N.N for asking jokerdino to write this.</sub>

I believe that appropriately tagging questions that are actually answered are far more important than those that are waiting to be answered. I will list down some of the points on why I think so.

- It makes the questions and answers much more easily discoverable and that is never a bad thing.
- It makes it much easier to track the various duplicates.

  - We have quite a huge number of duplicates that are yet to be closed, which we aren't doing the site any good by leaving open. I guess no one disagrees on that.
- It also ensures that the questions (and the huge volumes of good advice that comes with it in the form of comments and answers) doesn't get lost in the noise.

  - If a question only has one tag but probably could use another couple of relevant tags, people browsing for the latter will probably miss these questions. Again, it ties back to the initial point, that is, it makes our content much more discoverable.
- And, on a smaller scale, it gives those users at the 500 rep level something to do. This will make them feel encouraged and inspired and make them feel that they are contributing to the site one way or the other.

  - Perhaps, this will also drive people towards improving our tag-wiki and adding tag-wikis to tags that already doesn't have them?

So, I guess we should give some more attention to the tagging part of the question, which more often than not, gets overlooked for other outspoken components of the questions.
I suggest we start at the [greatest-hits](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2671/how-can-we-improve-the-greatest-hits-of-our-site) of our site first and eventually move on to other questions. Remember, while I point that we should focus on questions that are already answered, appropriately tagging questions that aren't already answered are useful as well.
We have a [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2455/ask-ubuntu-updaters) for users who focus on updating and improving our answers. Perhaps, we can use that room to collaborate on retagging the questions?

Comment: I wonder if this can be tied to the [clean up initiative](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cleanup) to further encourage it.

Comment: @N.N. Thats part of the point. :)

Comment: I was going to look through some questions and retag and add new tags where appropriate to help out. But as I'm not yet very high in the reputation stakes I'd be doing that by editing which would need to be peer-reviewed. Will this be annoying to the moderators?

Comment: @coversnail Helping is almost never annoying. We might "complain" about you and your editing habits (mainly because we notice if someone submits a ton of edits in a short period of time), but it's never a problem.