# Can we feature the style guide for new reviewers/editors?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

It would be nice to **highlight** the site's style guide for a bit on the sidebar *doohicky* on the main page:

- [Style guide for questions and answers](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/89/style-guide-for-questions-and-answers)

**I** for ***one*** am **finding** a `bunch` of *edits* **that** tend to **overdo** the *styling* and `I **think** it **would**` be a **good** thing if ***we*** reminded people that `this` just **makes** the *entire* thing **unreadable**.

This one wouldn't hurt either, or maybe just add them to the FAQ or something:

- [Editing tips and tricks](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/830/editing-tips-and-tricks)

Comment: +1 But I can't resist mentioning that **blinking text** is missing and desperately needed to make the question entirely un-readable. Can we please add blinking text for when users *really, really* need an answer fast?

Answer (score 8):

I **made** the *style guide* a **featured** `post`. Should

```
show
```

up in

> **"da bar"**

soon.

```
 __     _        _                                           _      _       __
||  ___| |_ __ _| |_ _   _ ___      ___ ___  _ __ ___  _ __ | | ___| |_ ___  ||
|| / __| __/ _` | __| | | / __|___ / __/ _ \| '_ ` _ \| '_ \| |/ _ \ __/ _ \ ||
|| \__ \ || (_| | |_| |_| \__ \___| (_| (_) | | | | | | |_) | |  __/ ||  __/ ||
|| |___/\__\__,_|\__|\__,_|___/    \___\___/|_| |_| |_| .__/|_|\___|\__\___| ||
||_                                                   |_|                   _||
```

Comment: I fear the knowledge will hurt the quality of the site.

Comment: Yes, the last thing the site needs is ASCII art :\