# Has rep required to edit questions been increased?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

The other night I suggested several edits to remove the word "Ubuntu" from titles as was suggested in a tip here ([editing-tips-and-tricks](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/830/editing-tips-and-tricks)). Now, edit is faded out under questions for me and tells me "Account is not allowed to suggest edits".

If I go under my account and select privileges, when I hover over "edit questions and answers" it states 2000 reputations are required. Does this include suggesting edits? If so, why was it changed?

I have made many edit suggestions since I've been here and would like to continue. Can someone tell me why suddenly I can't anymore?

Comment: Probably many of your edits rejected due to lowquality edits, Instead of just removing the word ubuntu(some times 'ubuntu' is essential), Try to improve content and formating of the post

Comment: Where Ubuntu was essential, I skipped over those questions.

Comment: Seems silly to reject improvements, please don't get discouraged!

Comment: Hey, @JorgeCastro has rejected plenty of my edits. ;) The moral of your particular story is that while they are good edits, you should look further-in-depth to the full question and figure out what *else* might need fixing. An editors job is never done! :)

Answer (score 5):

What happened was you suggested quite a number of minuscule edits that only edited out "Ubuntu" from the question title and ignored / overlooked the question body that did need quite some improvements as well.

So, I and others had to review the edits based on their merits, meaning significant efforts to improve the post were approved and other lazy attempts were either outright rejected or improved upon and marked as unhelpful. For example, compare your [suggested edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/57110) against [what I ended up editing it into](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/223549/3).

Since too many of your edits were rejected too soon, your ability to suggest edits has been [temporarily revoked for a week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled/81701#81701) or so.

When you are able to suggest edits, I would suggest you try to really improve the quality of the post instead of just removing "Ubuntu" from the title.

And regarding edit privileges, the reputation requirement has always been at 2000 rep but you do have the ability to suggest edits without the edit privileges.

Comment: My only intention with the edits was to clean up the titles, as suggested in the editing tips question I linked. That's all I focused on for that batch. This does not make it a low quality edit. To come back later to other more extensive body edits, etc. and as knowledge allows. Please update the editing tips question/answer to read that when cleaning up the titles, one should also go through the questions/answers to find things that need editing too.

Comment: @James It does make it a low quality edit. Don't just focus on one aspect of a question when you can fix many. Edits that are **too minor**, which we've taken to mean it only fixes one small aspect of another wise "troubled" question, are no good in our eyes. If you're going to take the time to edit (and bump the question) please edit the entire question to make it of higher quality. Titles are just one small portion of the quality game at Ask Ubuntu.