# Is there a page which teaches a user how to edit his question?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I need a cool-down after [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356597/file-permission-in-svn-repository?noredirect=1#comment461451_356597).

I wish there was a page which teaches a new user how to add information to his question. I couldn't find anything in the [about](https://askubuntu.com/about) or [help](https://askubuntu.com/help) page.

This would allow me to link to it and improve the chance that the asking user understands that I need him (or her) to edit and improve his question.

Can someone please start such a page? Maybe we could setup a Wiki question and something of this kind? I'd do it myself if I knew how.

Comment: I've written up a whole guide on this:

- http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/830/editing-tips-and-tricks

Comment: There's info on how the system works here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work also, if they can't find the `edit` button, you can always spoon feed it to them like this: [**edit your post with this link please**](http://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/7491/edit). Also, I don't think that 'how to edit' merits it's own wiki question. Maybe someone could edit ['Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?'](http://askubuntu.com/help/editing) to add this.

Comment: These two seem to give decent advice  http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-Intelligently. This one is from stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Damn. It's humbling to read those links and find things I'm doing wrong myself. That is, adding Ubuntu + version number to titles :P

Comment: @MadMike unless is a problem of an specific version of Ubuntu, the version normally is irrelevant (except when you need a GUI solution)

Comment: @MadMike it's ok, you can start doing searches and fixing em up relatively quickly!