# What should be edited out of the questions/anwers/posts in general?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Ok, everybody knows that the principle of the SE sites:

> All contributions are licensed under Creative Commons, and this site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. If you see something that needs improvement, click edit!

But! Lately I have been improving more edits that I would like to. So, lets remind the editors (users that suggest edits) what should be edited out in the posts:

- **Any formality**: be it greetings, signature, farewells, etc. Anything that makes the post looks like a letter should be removed.
- **Thanks**: Thanks in the StackExchange sites are expressed with upvotes when you have enough privileges, hence saying thanks in the post only generate noise.
- **ASAPness**: thinks like "please help me", "I need this ASAP", "anyone knows?", etc. should be edited. We are a community that is glad to help, but sometimes becomes grumpy if the OP put pressure in us. If someone knows the answer and comes across your question it will be highly probable that it answers.
- **Basic grammar**: I've seen edits that only adds spaces in the code blocks, but don't fix anything else, like I's. Formatting things is good, it makes the post looks more presentable, but the grammar, and orthography should improve along with the edit.
- **Titles of the questions**: each time I have to read *"problem in 13.10"*, or *"update error"* in a suggested edit I get fuming mad. That doesn't help anyone to know what the question is about, so when proposing the edit, check if the title of the question is an excerpt of what OP is asking in the body. It also helps for the Search Engine Optimization (SEO) so people can find the questions that might have already answer easier ([NathanOsman](http://meta.askubuntu.com/users/5/nathan-osman) asked a [duplicate question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19236789/792066), which he may have found earlier, if it had a better title).
- **Email addresses** (thanks to Rizwind for remember it)

Those are the most glaring edits/improvements that I have to do to edits. Also remember that if you are going to edit a post, look for any improvements that can be made! Nothing is too good for SE, things can always be improved. If I still see post that has glaring improvements that I have to improve I will improve them and mark that the suggested edit as not helpful (since it was too minor).

Another thing when suggesting edits is to check the tags. Tags keep the site organized by sections, look for tags that are either relevant or not to the question and change them so the correct people can see them. If a question is about installing a game in wine and only have the installation tag, add the wine tag along with any other relevant tag. Is probable that the installation tag won't be relevant in some cases.

For the reviewers, please guide users more strongly about the edits done in the posts. Also if you see anything that can be improved (as listed above) please do so.

Comment: Regarding title - only edit them if you can make it more meaningful; otherwise let it be and someone else would take up the task of improving the title..

Comment: I don't agree on the item "Basic grammar": formatting the code blocks to make the thing readable and understandable is a very good thing™ in itself. Correcting grammar and spelling is important too but unless the mistakes lead to misunderstandings I'd approve an edit with substantial improvement in readability even if it leaves grammar issues untouched.

Comment: This question is all (-.-) When did common sense abandon people's bodies and then did the need for general sense turn in a rule based discussion?

Comment: @BrunoPereira beats me... really, I'm in awe

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: ...must control inner urge to edit "fixes" in grammar section...

Comment: @BlueIce mm... seems that I was using the noun there instead the verb...

Comment: @guntbert ok, but how about 10, 20, 30 edits that only do that where there are obviously more glaring problem with posts?

Comment: @Braiam and all of the other grammar mistakes...

Comment: I remove email addresses also.

Comment: > Ok, everybody knows that the principle of the SE sites:  

No, everyone does not know that, and assuming that is counter-productive.

Comment: @kiloseven I'm targetting a couple of users that has enough reputation to know how the sites works, and I'm **quoting again** the help page, just in case someone doesn't know. I'm not assuming anything, but you are assuming that *I* am assuming. And the message got across just by the number of upvotes.

Comment: Up votes from the folks who have found 'meta', a self-selecting group.

Comment: @kiloseven ok, you are trying to find fault in pretty things, everyone that uses the SE sites after a while should have read the entire help section, if they didn't is their problem when they hit themself against the wall. The warnings were there for all to read.

Answer (score 4):

Can you integrate this with the exiting editing guide?

- [Editing tips and tricks](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/830/editing-tips-and-tricks)

Comment: It seems it's existing. I'm glad it didn't exit! ;-D