# Questions including "Please help me"

Tags: discussion, editing

I have been getting most of my reputation from editing posts because most of the questions are beyond me.  I have noticed that many people, especially people with only 1 reputation, will include things in their question that basically mean, "Please help me!"  Since they are asking the question, it is obvious they want help.  Should I remove things like this from questions?  I can see how people want something at the end asking for help so it doesn't look like they are just describing a problem, but it seems much more useful to describe there goal at the end.  For example, they describe the problem and then say, "please help me do this (but be very specific)."

Comment: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7510/what-should-be-edited-out-of-the-questions-anwers-posts-in-general

Comment: IMO, many of those kinds of things should be safe to edit out.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"Help me please", "anticipated thanks", "my immortal and cool name", taglines, salutations, etc. **are just noise**, they don't add anything to the question and should go. Also, check tagging and title when proposing suggested edits, fix as many problems as you can find in the post.

Relevant [What should be edited out of the questions/anwers/posts in general?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7510/what-should-be-edited-out-of-the-questions-anwers-posts-in-general)