# How to format release versions?

Tags: discussion, editing

When making other edits to a question that mentions a release/number (e.g, Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS), my natural instinct is to bold it as it is usually the first thing I look for in a question and I have read that we try to [keep it out of titles and tags](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/830/editing-tips-and-tricks).

What is the general consensus for how to format this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no real way to format it, and adding things as 'bold' just for the heck of it when it was never bold to begin with is a sure-fire way to get rejected edits as "Doesn't help readability."

I'd just leave the versions alone, and do nothing, and not bother editing for the sake of just making that one tiny bit more prevalent.  I'd leave it alone.  Bold if you must, but if you do that, also actually *improve* the post somehow - don't just "bold the version" and do nothing.

Comment: Great answer. I will stick to leaving it alone then.

Comment: I'd suggest another reason for leaving it alone. _Sometimes_ the version can be significant, in more that just "is it current." Most of the time, however, the version makes no difference in the issue, or the answer. Highlighting the version, then, doesn't actually increase the information in the posting, and could even be a distraction from the important information.